# How to fill a 2D array with class objects inside a for loop?

Tags: c#

```
dailyMenu [,] daysOfMonth = new dailyMenu[4,5];
for (int column = 0; column < daysOfMonth.Length; column++) 
{
    for (int row = 0; row < daysOfMonth.Length; row++) 
    {
        dailyMenu dm = new dailyMenu ();

    }
}
```

My question is I want to know how to fill my 2D array with new objects of my dailyMenu class?

Comment: The above code is what I have so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 2-D array, you probably want to get the length by GetLength(0) and GetLength(1) instead of by using Length:

```
dailyMenu [,] daysOfMonth = new dailyMenu[4,5];
    for (int column = 0; column < daysOfMonth.GetLength(0); column++) 
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < daysOfMonth.GetLength(1); row++) 
        {
            dailyMenu dm = new dailyMenu ();
            //do something on dm
            daysOfMonth[column,row] = dm; //assign it like this
        }
    }
```

This is because GetLength has argument of dimension index (0, 1, 2, etc...) Which can give you the length of the array in that dimension (0 being the *first* dimension - in your case *column*, and 1 being the *second* - in your case *row*. Length does not have that.

To assign a value to the array, simply access the array by the dimension indexes (*column* and *row*) in the *correct* order - otherwise you will get IndexOutOfRange exception:

```
daysOfMonth[column,row] = dm; //correct
daysOfMonth[row,column] = dm; //wrong, exception on 5,0
```

Comment: OOOOH okay i get it now

Comment: Not to be mean but could you also help me out on how to print this to the console?

Comment: Print it? Yes, it is possible using Console.WriteLine(). But that depends on what you want to print and how your dailyMenu class look like. What do you want to print? How the class look like?

Comment: I just want to print each object that ive just created out to the console. My dailymenu class has a day of the week, an entree, a price for it, and how much calories it has

Comment: Then you can try: Console.WriteLine("day of week: " + dm.DayOfWeek + ", entree: " + dm.Entree + ", Price: " + dm.Price + ", Calories: " + dm.Calories); and so on... More conservative approach would be to *override* the *ToString()* method with whatever you want to print when you call dm.ToString()

Comment: In that case then you should use the conventional method: overriding *ToString()* in your *dailyMenu* with whatever you want to print and then call it like this: Console.WriteLine(dm.ToString())

Comment: Alright it works now except for the fact Im getting a index out of boundary

Comment: Just to be respectful to this site's rule, I think you better make a new post for that rather than updating the current post.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is I want to know how fill my 2D array with new objects of my dailyMenu class?

After initializing dm.

`daysOfMonth[column,row] = dm`

Comment: SO this will populate my 2D array with different objects of my dailymenu class?

Comment: This will populate your array with whatever you have given to `dm` . So basically yes because you use `new` so it creates new objects with each loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.GetLength()` to find out the length of a dimension. Alternatively just use the same constants you use in 2D array constructor.

```
dailyMenu [,] daysOfMonth = new dailyMenu[4,5];
for (int column = 0; column < daysOfMonth.GetLength(0); column++) 
{
    for (int row = 0; row < daysOfMonth.GetLength(1); row++) 
    {
        daysOfMonth[column,row] = new dailyMenu ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew it was something related to that